# What is the correct tasks.json config for compiling typescript in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Using `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`B` I added a default tasks.json file and uncommented the second task runner block. I have a typescript file in the root of the directory and a tsconfig.json.

Everytime I compile I get 'error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'p'. What is the correct definition to allow me to compile a typescript file? Can all files be compiled in one go even if they are in subdirectories?

I have tried changing the args below to `["${file}"]` which simply allows me to compile the file that is open. This works. I've also run the tsc command from the command prompt and no -p or -project arguments exists.

tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",

    // The command is tsc. Assumes that tsc has been installed using npm install -g typescript
    "command": "tsc",

    // The command is a shell script
    "isShellCommand": true,

    // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur. 
    "showOutput": "silent",

    // Tell the tsc compiler to use the tsconfig.json from the open folder.
    "args": ["-p", "."],

    // use the standard tsc problem matcher to find compile problems
    // in the output.
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES5",
        "module": "amd",
        "sourceMap": true
    }
}
```

VS Code: v0.30

TypeScript: v1.4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem. It was a wrong PATH variable to the TypeScript compiler. (try to type `tsc -v` in a command window). The `tsconfig.json` is supported in TypeScript version 1.5. My PATH variable was set to version 1. 
When I changed the system PATH variable to the updated installation folder (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.5`) and a restart of Visual Studio Code, everything was fine.
(Remove all entries from the `args`!) Like:

```js
{
    "version": "0.1.0",

    // The command is tsc. Assumes that tsc has been installed using npm install -g typescript
    "command": "tsc",

    // The command is a shell script
    "isShellCommand": true,

    // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur. 
    "showOutput": "always",

    // Tell the tsc compiler to use the tsconfig.json from the open folder.
    "args": [],

    // use the standard tsc problem matcher to find compile problems
    // in the output.
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

Comment: Where can I find an installer for 1.5?

Comment: Install the latest version: npm install -g typescript, look for the installed files and set the PATH. Or what I did (because I have Visual Studio with Typescript installed): I downloaded the installer for Visual Studio from the Typescript website.

Comment: yes, using the npm it would only ever install 1.4 unless I explicitly used the version option. Using the Visual Studio installer was easier followed by adding the path to the Path system variable.

Comment: an alternative is to check version `tsc -v` is >1.5 then have a dedicated cmd window watching updates in folder `tsc -w`

Answer (score 4):

I struggled until I understood how npm was installing the typescript 1.5 beta (or not) on my windows laptop.

The key to getting this to work for me was:

1. uninstall current version of typescript (for me, this was version 1.4.1)

   > npm uninstall -g typescript
2. install 1.5.1-beta version

   > npm install -g typescript@1.5.0-beta
   >   (npm will print an error message & list all versions if you use an incorrect version)
3. Locate the tsc.cmd file - created under the npm folder.  On my Windows 8.1 machine, this was stored at:
   C:\Users\Bob.Chiverton\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc.cmd
4. Add this to the tasks.json file:
   "command": "C:\Users\Bob.Chiverton\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc.cmd",

Now re-try ctrl-Shift-B.

-bob

Answer (score 2):

Support for tsconfig.json was added as part of version 1.5

Roadmap:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap

Commit:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/1692